# Draw image view height and width before loading from url

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am getting image's height and width from API. I'm using Picasso to load images from url. My query is once we would get the API response how can we draw image as per it's height and width before actual image loading by Picasso. I have set image's height and width to Picasso in resize() method.

But Picasso loads images directly once image successfully downloaded. Here the issue is that I want draw image's height and width in preloading state.

```
/*
* set image view's height and width from API 
*/
int imageViewHeight = getHeight();
int imageViewWidth = getWidth();

// picasso to laod an image from url
Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                    .load(url).placeholder(getGradientDrawable())
                    .resize(imageViewWidth, imageViewHeight)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(imageView);

// gradient for placeholder
static GradientDrawable getGradientDrawable() {
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        return gradientDrawable;
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: added the code. I will add any thing you want..

Comment: Can please remove centerInside() and try, because I feel that it is messing up things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you right but if you want a place holder for your image while Picasso doing a background download, you can use `placeholder()` function like below:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(drawable).into(imageview);
```

you can create a `drawable` with your desired width and height or use a `resource ID`

Comment: I have used placeholder too. But with no success. 
Facebook draws each and every view as per height and width before actual view gets loaded. How can we achieve so ?

Comment: @MohanishNerurkar with facebook, images which needs to be rendered (like profile photos) has predefined sizes

Comment: Completely agree with you. Even I am getting the sizes of the images from API and using those in Picasso in resize() function.

Answer (score 0):

This helped do it for me, setting the imageview max and min height and width to the image's dimensions before calling the Picasso library to load the URL. It might help someone else who is looking at this.

```
imageView.setMinimumWidth(Integer.parseInt(this.reply_list_full.get(position).getImage_width()));
imageView.setMinimumHeight(Integer.parseInt(this.reply_list_full.get(position).getImage_width()));

imageView.setMaxWidth(Integer.parseInt(this.reply_list_full.get(position).getImage_width()));
imageView.setMaxHeight(Integer.parseInt(this.reply_list_full.get(position).getImage_width()));
```